# How to display date in a specific format depending on the locale in Yii2 (Russian — php:d.m.Y and English - php:m/d/Y)?

Tags: php, date, formatting, yii2

I want to display the date (for example, 10 APR 2006) in a format specified in the config. Russian - 10.04.2006 and English 4.10.2006.

In the config you can set the formatter for preset templates of type short, medium, long, full. Which format the date like this:

- short: 10.04.06 и 4/10/06;
- medium: 10 апр. 2006 г. и Apr 10, 2006;
- full: понедельник, 10 апреля 2006 г. и Monday, April 10, 2006
- long: 10 апреля 2006 г. и April 10, 2006.

How to specify the formats: 10.04.2006 (rus) and 4.10.2006 (eng)?

Comment: you can define `timeZone` for this in `Formatter` read more. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html

Comment: How this is related to the date formatting?

Answer (score 0):

In Yii2 Basic App. add `formatter` in **config->web.php**

```
'components' => [
     'formatter' => [
        'timeZone' => 'Asia/Kolkata',
        'dateFormat' => 'dd-MM-yyyy', //Date format to used here
        'datetimeFormat' => 'php:d-m-Y H:i:s',
        'timeFormat' => 'php:h:i:s A',
        'decimalSeparator' => '.',
        'thousandSeparator' => '',
        'class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter',
      ],
 ]
```

Refer this link [Yii2 Formatter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html)

Comment: How to specify the formats: 10.04.2006 (rus) and 4.10.2006 (eng)?